# Problems with cell.detailTextLabel.text (No duplicate)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a problem with cell.detailTextLabel.text = NULL, like others before me. I've read those threads, but can't solve my problem. I'm using storyboard and my Table View is using Dynamic Prototypes as content. I have one prototyps cell that has the identifier "myCell" and I'm using Subtitle as style. I've done this a couple of times before and that worked like expected, but this time something is wrong. Code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    MyClass *myClass = [self sectionNumber:indexPath.section rowNumber:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myClass.someProperty];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Some text";
    NSLog(@"%@", cell.detailTextLabel.text);

    return cell;
}
```

What am I missing? The NSLog is printing out "NULL".

Hank

Comment: Replace `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];` with `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];` and try

Comment: Still the same problem :/

Comment: is detailLabel has instance?

Comment: @iHank change cell `style` to `Subtitle` in Attribute inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think You are missing the check to see if cell is nil or not

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle      reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    }

MyClass *myClass = [self sectionNumber:indexPath.section rowNumber:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myClass.someProperty];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Some text";
NSLog(@"%@", cell.detailTextLabel.text);

return cell;
```

Try replace the code within the function with the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"myCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    MyClass *myClass = [self sectionNumber:indexPath.section rowNumber:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myClass.someProperty];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Some text";
    NSLog(@"%@", cell.detailTextLabel.text);

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: In story board you don't need to allocate it.

Comment: That worked if I remove the if-statement. Thank you! Can't figure out why it didn't work with only the StoryBoard.

Comment: Glad to help ;). But why accept the other newer answer, which is basically the same as mine >< ?

Comment: I think that I mixed them up in some way. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Change cell **Style** to `Subtitle` in Attribute inspector by ,

[image]

[image]

From [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_7) it says that, `detailTextLabel` returns the secondary label of the table cell if one exists. And if the style doesn’t support detail labels, nil is returned.